# In-line temporary tables in Derby (like DB2)

Tags: sql, syntax, db2, derby

Does Derby have an equivalent syntax for in-line temporary tables such as these:

(this is valid DB2 syntax):

```
    with data(a,b) as (values
                        ('a',10),
                        ('b',20),
                        ('c',30),
                        ('d',40)
                      )
    select * from data
```

Thanks,

Pradyumna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, but this works in Derby:

select a,b from (values ('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('c', 30)) as x(a,b);

Answer (score 3):

> 'DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE (table-name)' etcera

I found this by googling on "Derby Temp Tables", it's the #1 result, and straight from the docs:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html

Comment: too bad it is not what OP was asking though. that's a temporary table but not an in-line table